# Moving mysql database from one server to another server

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, backup, database-backups

I want to move my mysql database from rackspace server to aws server.Is there any way to do it easily.It contains more or less 1 million rows of data

Comment: Is it possible to make use of mysqldump on aws server?

Comment: Why can't you just use mysqldump?

Comment: is it a live site? how much concerned are you about your downtime?

Comment: @krishna My site is a live site..so how can i move it without any downtime

Comment: if you have just one db(master) server and wanted to migrate to a different physical machine, i dont think its possible to do it without downtime. choose a technique which helps you to do this with least downtime. Try showing something like "Site under maintainence", keep every server software installed and configured in your new machine, move all your code files and finally migrate the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is not a live site and downtime is not an issue, you can try the below

```
#step1: take a dump of your db
>mysqldump –-user root –-password=myrootpassword db_test > db_test.sql

#step2: zip the .sql file - this is optional
>gzip db_test.sql

#step3: transfer the file to AWS using .pem file
>scp -i myAmazonKey.pem db_test.sql.gz ec2-user@<ur_ip_address>:~/.

#step4: login to your AWS instance 

#step5: unzip the file
>gunzip db_test.sql.gz

#step6: import the db to your AWS mysql instance
>mysql -u username -p password db_name < db_test.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below steps,

```
Old Server

    Stop mysql server
    Copy contents of datadir to another location on disk (~/mysqldata/*)
    Start mysql server again (downtime was 10-15 minutes)
    compress the data (tar -czvf mysqldata.tar.gz ~/mysqldata)
    copy the compressed file to new server

New Server

    install mysql (don't start)
    unzip compressed file (tar -xzvf mysqldata.tar.gz)
    move contents of mysqldata to the datadir
    Make sure your innodb_log_file_size is same on new server, or if it's not, don't copy the old log files (mysql will generate these)
    Start mysql
```